# Odoo 8 src variable for iframe in ir.ui.view

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, odoo, odoo-8

Model

```
class ItemStocks(models.Model):
    _name = 'item.stocks'

    item_url = fields.Char('View Item')
ItemStocks()
```

View

```
<record id="view_item_stocks_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">item.stocks.form</field>
    <field name="model">item.stocks</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Item Stocks">
        ...
            <page string="Live Site">
                 <form string="Embedded Webpage" version="7.0" edit="false">
                      <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"
                                        src="{Variable for this.item_url}" width="100%" height="1000"/>
                 </form>
            </page>
      ...
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

How can I replace {Variable for this.item_url} with a valid expression for the field in model? Is there a better way to do like this? What would you prefer to solve the requirement of showing dynamically an embedded webpage?

Context: Odoo 8, New Api, ir.ui.view

Answer (score 2):

```
  **`Image Url wise Set Dynamic Iframe In Odoo`**
# v11 odoo community
you need to create  fields like this :
image_url = fields.Char('Image Url')
img_attach = fields.Html('Image Html')


# set image_url in iframe
     @api.onchange('image_url')
     def onchange_image_url(self):
         if self.image_url:
             self.img_attach = '<img id="img" src="%s"/>' % self.image_url
# set image_url in form view 
     <field name="image_url" />
# after added script
        <script>
        if(document.getElementById("img")){
           var value= document.getElementById("img").src;
           document.getElementById("custom_src").src=value; 
         }
        </script>


# also set iframe in form view
      <iframe id="custom_src" src="" width="200" height="200"  />     

#output
show the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x7et.png
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: ya sure . i Updated My Answer.Thank u.

Comment: thank you! I confirm it still works, in V13. And its great for any kind of link, if you want to display any webapp in the form view. But you must use <img> tag